# как при загрузке страницы каждый раз переместить div-ы

Tags: javascript, html

как сделать так чтобы при загрузке страницы каждый раз div-ы перместились местами
плюс к этому у всех одинаковый класс

```
<div class = "x">1</div>
<div class = "x">2</div>
<div class = "x">3</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как-то так хотите?

```js
let divs = document.getElementsByClassName("x");
let newDivs = [...divs].sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
newDivs.forEach(item => main.appendChild(item));
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class = "x">1</div>
  <div class = "x">2</div>
  <div class = "x">3</div>
</div>
```

Нажимайте несколько раз чтобы увидеть разницу